# Boost test expected throw

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have a test on a code part that needs to throw an exception, but using `BOOST_CHECK_THROW` still crashes the test. Here is the test:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "tools/CQueueMessage.hpp"

class TestMessage
{
public:
    std::string m_message1;
    std::string m_message2;
    std::string m_messageEmpty;
    std::string m_messageEmptyJson;

    TestMessage()
    :   m_message1("{\"photo\":{\"name\":\"pic\",\"extension\":\"jpg\"}}"),
        m_message2("{\"photo\":{\"name\":\"pic\",\"extension\":\"png\"}}"),
        m_messageEmpty(""), m_messageEmptyJson("{}") {}
    ~TestMessage() {}
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(message2send, TestMessage)
{
    QueueMessage qmsg1(m_message1);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(qmsg1.messageToBeSent(), "{\"photo\":{\"name\":\"pic\",\"extension\":\"jpg\"}}");

    QueueMessage qmsg2(m_message2);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(qmsg2.messageToBeSent(), "{\"photo\":{\"name\":\"pic\",\"extension\":\"png\"}}");

    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(QueueMessage qmsg3(m_messageEmpty), QueueMessageException)
//  QueueMessage qmsg4(m_messageEmptyJson);
}
```

The `QueueMessage` class constructor is throwing a `QueueMessageException` if the message is empty or if it is an empty json. My problem is that this test is printing:

```
Running 1 test case...
unknown location(0): fatal error in "message2send": std::exception: Bad message format

*** 1 failure detected in test suite "main"
*** Exited with return code: 201 ***
```

How can I verify that the exception is thrown?

---

This is the constructor:

```
QueueMessage(CString& messageIn)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << messageIn;
    PTree pt;
    json::read_json(ss, pt);
    std::string photo = pt.get< std::string >("photo");
    if (photo.empty())
    {
        throw QueueMessageException("Bad message format"); // in debugging it arrives here
    }
}
```

Comment: The strange part is that `read_json` should already throw, but with a different error message. And for the emptyJson test, this `pt.get()` variant should also throw, but again a different error message.

Comment: You could set a breakpoint in the constructor and before the throw, and run it in the debugger. You could replace the boost macro with an explicit try catch, using separate catch for QueueMessageException, const QueueMessageException&, std::exception. And if you want to control the exceptions, the constructor should catch everything and then throw its own QueueMessageException.

Comment: Ok, I have tried not to post the whole code, and it seems that it was a problem of child... It was throwing the exception in the first call of the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that your constructor is NOT in fact throwing `QueueMessageException`. It looks like it (through the function `message2send`) is throwing `std::exception` or a different child of it.